# camera rotation issue in three.js

Tags: rotation, three.js, perspectivecamera

I am using three.js to create a tube geometry and have a feature where the camera rotates to particular angle with the click of a radio button.
To rotate the camera, I tried using below code:

```
camera.rotation.set(2.88, -0.9, -2.0);
camera.position.set(-1800, 0, -1200);
```

It doesn't have any effect. but when i use the same code by first setting auto rotation update to false, it works

```
camera.rotationAutoUpdate = false;
camera.rotation.set(2.88, -0.9, -2.0);
camera.position.set(-1800, 0, -1200);
```

The issue with setting rotationAutoUpdate to false is that once the rotation is set, if i try to rotate the tube with mouse event, it messes up the whole rotation functionality. And if i try to set it to true again, the above required rotation effect is not visible.

Please suggest, if I am doing something wrong or if i am missing out something? Thanks

Comment: Are you using `CombinedCamera`? `camera.rotationAutoUpdate` appears to be old code that is not used.

Comment: No, I am using Perspective camera and working on r53 version of three.js
Is there any way to fix it in this version (r53), as I have done quite a bit of work over this version itself and currently doesn't want to spend lot of time to make it compatible to latest version.  Thanks

Comment: three.js r53 is a year old. I strongly suggest you upgrade to the current version. See the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading.